# Index XML files in Apache Solr as plain text

Tags: java, xml, solr, solrj

Is there any way to dump all contents of xml file in a single content field??

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

code used for indexing

```
HttpUrlConnection solrHttpURLConnection = "http://localhost:7892/solr/myCore/update/extract?literal.id=1234&commit=true "
solrHttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
solrHttpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
solrHttpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
solrHttpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
solrHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", type);
solrHttpURLConnection.connect();
```

i am taking outputstream from this url and writing contents by taking input stream from dataServer.

NOTE:

1. the above code works for all file formats except xml,csv and json.
2. no error message is coming from solr

Sample XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>just a test
</content>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the content type to "text/xml"
2. Add the following lines to your code:
   OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(solrHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
   writer.write(your_xml_file);
   writer.flush();
3. Execute the request with this url http://localhost:7892/solr/myCore/update?literal.id=1234&commit=true
   For json files use /update/json/docs
4. Please also check this documentation about uploading data with index handlers https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-XMLUpdateCommands